# Donald L. Cohn, "Measure Theory" (2nd ed., 2013), Exercises 2.4.9 and 2.5.5: are there unnecessary hypotheses, or have I misunderstood the questions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

From Donald L. Cohn, *Measure Theory* (2nd ed., 2013):

> [Exercise 2.4.9] Let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, let
> $g$ be a $[0, +\infty]$-valued integrable function on $X,$ and let
> $f$ and $f_t$ (for $t$ in $[0, +\infty)$) be real-valued
> $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$ such that
> $$
> f(x) = \lim_{t \to +\infty} f_t(x)
> $$
> and
> $$
> |f_t(x)| \leq g(x) \text{ for } t \text{ in } [0, +\infty)
> $$
> hold at almost every $x$ in $X.$ Show that
> $\int f\,d\mu = \lim_{t \to +\infty} \int f_t\, d\mu.$ (Hint: Give
> a simplified version of the argument in Example 2.4.6.)

Example 2.4.6, which I needn't quote, is a justification of
differentiation under the integral sign, whose relevance lies in its
use of a result from an appendix:

> **C.7.** Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d,$ let $f$ be a
> real- or complex-valued function on $A,$ and let $a$ be a limit
> point of $A.$ [$\ldots$] One can check that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$
> if and only if $\lim_n f(x_n) = L$ for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ of
> elements of $A,$ all different from $a,$ such that $\lim_n x_n = a.$

When doing the exercise, I was a bit worried, because I couldn't
understand the reason for requiring $f$ and $f_t$ to be real-valued
rather than $[-\infty, +\infty]$-valued.

I went ahead and gave this argument in my handwritten notes (because
I wasn't yet worried enough to type it up in $\LaTeX{}$ for checking,
or for asking a question in Maths.SE):

**Proposition.**
Let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, let $g$ be a
$[0, +\infty]$-valued $\mu$-integrable function on $X,$ and let $f$
be a $[-\infty, +\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function
on $X.$
Let $T$ be a first-countable topological space, $A$ a subset of $T,$
and $a$ a limit point of $A.$ Suppose that $f_t,$ for $t \in A,$ is
a $[-\infty, +\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function on
$X$ such that
$$
f(x) = \lim_{\substack{t \to a \\ t \in A}} f_t(x)
$$
and
$$
|f_t(x)| \leqslant g(x) \text{ for } t \text{ in } A
$$
hold at almost every $x$ in $X.$ Then
$$
\label{cohn:measure:2:ex:2.4.9:eq:1}\tag{$1$}
\int f\,d\mu = \lim_{\substack{t\to a \\ t\in A}} \int f_t(x)\,d\mu.
$$

*Proof.*
Let $(t_n)_{n \geqslant 1}$ be any sequence in $A \setminus \{a\}$
such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}t_n = a.$ Define a sequence
$(h_n)_{n \geqslant 1}$ of $[-\infty, +\infty]$-valued
$\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$ by $h_n(x) = f_{t_n}(x).$
Then
$$
f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} h_n(x)
$$
and
$$
|h_n(x)| \leqslant g(x) \quad (n \geqslant 1)
$$
hold for $\mu$-almost all $x \in X.$ Therefore, by the DCT
(Theorem 2.4.5 in Cohn),
$$
\int f\,d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int h_n\,d\mu =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_{t_n}\,d\mu.
$$
The required result \eqref{cohn:measure:2:ex:2.4.9:eq:1} now follows
from the obvious generalisation of C.7. $\ \square$

This argument seemed (and still seems) so straightforward that I
never seriously thought there could be anything badly wrong with it,
until I came to the later exercise:

> [Exercise 2.5.5] Show that if
> $f \in  \mathscr{L}^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda,
> \mathbb{R}),$ then
> $$
> \int_{\mathbb{R}} f\,d\lambda =
> \lim_{\substack{a \to -\infty \\b \to +\infty}}
> \int_{[a, b]} f\,d\lambda.
> $$
> (Hint: Use the dominated convergence theorem and a modification of
> the hint given for Exercise 2.4.9.)

I have two worries about this exercise.  The smaller worry is the
same as before: I do not see why $f$ has to be real-valued, rather
than $[-\infty, +\infty]$-valued.  The vector space properties of
the set $\mathscr{L}^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}), \lambda,
\mathbb{R})$ - in particular, its closure under addition - seem
to play no role in the question.  Nor is Riemann integration
involved, in spite of the exercise's location at the end of a
section on that topic.  So these two possible explanations can be
ruled out.

Cohn is a careful author. (I absolutely love this book, by the way!)
He does not throw unnecessary hypotheses around at random.  So
there is already reason, from these two exercises, to suspect that I
have misunderstood something at a pretty deep level.  Still, the
point is small enough - like several other smallish difficulties I
have had in studying the book on my own - that I would see no
need to ask a question about it in Maths.SE, were it not for a
larger worry.

The larger worry is the appearance of the $\sigma$-algebra
$\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$ Why
isn't it $\mathscr{M}_{\lambda^*}(\mathbb{R}),$ the $\sigma$-algebra
of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

(I notice belatedly that Exercise 2.4.10 also contains a hypothesis
of Borel measurability, which my long and messy handwritten answer -
my computer has recently become so erratic that I have fallen
back on writing notes by hand - does not appear to have used.  I
won't complicate this already long question by detailing that
exercise too, but I may later ask a separate question about it.)

Setting these worries aside, the exercise seems straightforward
(especially as I'd proved a general enough version of C.7 when
doing the first exercise). Thus:

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to [-\infty, +\infty]$ be a Lebesgue
integrable function.  The space
$T = [-\infty, +\infty] \times [-\infty, +\infty]$ is
first-countable, and $(-\infty, +\infty)$ is a limit point of the
set $A = \{(a, b) \in T : -\infty < a < b < +\infty\},$ so the DCT
(with $|f|$ as the bound), together with the generalised version of
C.7, shows that
$$
\int f\,d\lambda = \lim_{(a, b) \to (-\infty, +\infty)}
\int f\chi_{[a, b]}\,d\lambda =
\lim_{\substack{a \to -\infty \\ b \to +\infty}}
\int_a^b f\,d\lambda.
$$

But am I merely fooling myself into thinking that these are valid
solutions?

Comment: If $f$ is integrable then the set $\{x:|f|=\infty\}$  has measure $0$, so you might as redefined the function $f$ on that set as set it to say $0$ (or $1$ to whatever you want). Thus, it is enough to assume that $f$ is real. The rest is dominated convergence (take sequences monotone sequences $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}a$ and $b_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}b$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Does the hypothesis that $f$ is real-valued simplify the proof?

Comment: @OliverDiaz The definition of the integral in Cohn's book (which does not seem unusual in this respect) suffers no complication from the possible existence of infinite values of $f.$ Rather it is the hypothesis that there are no such values (a hypothesis which Cohn makes elsewhere for good reasons) that seems to be a complication in this exercise.

Comment: Right. However, in the proof of the dominated convergence you deal with expressions of the form  $2|g|-|f-f_n|$ or $g-f_n$, so to avoid those inconsistencies (which again happened in sets of measure $0$) by redefining your functions in sets of measure $0$, you don't have to deal with this pesky inconsequential situations.

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained that Cohn normally works with $[-\infty, +\infty]$-valued functions, imposing a restriction to $[0, +\infty]$ or $[0, +\infty)$ or $(-\infty, +\infty)$ only when such a restriction is needed in order for a particular result to hold; and I was puzzled because such a restriction does not seem necessary in either of these cases. But I assumed that no-one would respond to the question unless they had a copy of the book to hand, in which case such an explanation would be unnecessary.

Comment: I know the book very well... the point is that when you prove certain theorems, operations such as $|f-f_n|$ are used. This cause problem when you functions take the values $\pm\infty$. But since things that occur in sets of measure $0$ are inconsequential, you might as well remove those complications by redefining functions so that you deal with real value objects. That does not affect the validity of theorems since bad things only happen in sets of measure $0$.

Comment: I hope these comments don't cause anyone else to imagine that I don't understand that perfectly familiar point (which is covered very clearly in the book).

Comment: @CalumGilhooley This comment is not relevant to this question at hand but this exercise seems pointless to me. In Exercise 2.4.9, we can just consider the sequence $\{ f_n \}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and this sequence satisfies the hypothesis of the Dominated Convergence Theorem and $\lim_{t\to +\infty} f_t (x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n (x)$ holds for at every $x \in X$. Thus, the exercise follows. Is my argument correct?

Comment: @meth- If we define a function $\varphi \colon [0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\varphi(t) = \int f_t\,d\mu,$ then your argument shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty,n\in\mathbb{N}}\varphi(n) = \int f\,d\mu$; but to prove that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\varphi(t) = \int f\,d\,\mu,$ as the exercise requires, does seem to need the application of a principle similar to item C.7 in Appendix C of Cohn's book. Given such a principle, the exercise verges on the trivial, which seems to be what worries you. Does that make sense? (My recollection of this material is quite murky. I should pick up Cohn's book again!)